# How to convert unicoded dict into a string

Tags: python, type-conversion

My issue is as follows. We have dict that has all keys and values as unicode, example:

```
ab = {
    u'a': u'A',
    u'b': u'B',
    u'c': u'C',
}
```

I want to convert it into a string. Obviously when I do:

```
str(ab)
```

I will receive:

```
"{u'a': u'A', u'c': u'C', u'b': u'B'}"
```

If I do:

```
unicode(ab)
```

I will receive:

```
u"{u'a': u'A', u'c': u'C', u'b': u'B'}"
```

My expected result is:

```
"{'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B'}"
```

For the moment I found that if I do json.dumps it will convert it properly into a string without extra 'u' before each key and value, but it will also change True into true and other javascript dialect differences.

Any workaround different than iterating recursively over my data sctructure?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this string representation?

Comment: I agree that the goals here probably matter a lot with regards to the best way (or not) to do this.

Comment: legacy code, it's just assumes that we have stringified data structures in database that can be decoded on retrieval

Comment: @Drachenfels If you can change that, then please, for your own sake, do so. It's a terrible idea from the point of view of the database, and from the point of view of the code.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, recently we've upgraded version of django, all fields are unicode, so our dictionaries are unicoded and our code was casting dicts to string, unicoded dicts means we have totally corrupted data in db. In the end, it's huge fail that I cannot do anything about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you will need to convert each item to a string manually, then string the dict, and note that unless the Unicode data happens to all be ASCII, you could run into problems. Making that assumption, you can use a dict comprehension to make it quicker and more concise:

```
print({str(key): str(value) for key, value in ab.items()})
{'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B'}
```

If you are using a version of Python prior to 2.7.3, without dict comprehensions:

```
dict((str(key), str(value)) for key, value in ab.items())
```

Comment: The OP explains why they don't want to use JSON.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sort of, but (s)he doesn't explain what they will use the data for and why it is important to keep it as a Python literal. In most cases, encoding/decoding from JSON is a better idea.

Comment: As the problem was explained further in the comments, I removed the note about JSON - using it would be almost as bad in this case anyway.

Comment: Rather than `str(x)` it might be better to do `x.encode('utf-8')` to preserve any non-ASCII Unicode characters.

Comment: @MarkRansom This is true, although that may not be what the asker wanted. I was sticking to what the asker showed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2.x:

```
dict( map(str, item) for item in ab.iteritems() )
```

Comment: Why is this exclusive to 2.x? It's easy enough to change the call from `iteritems()` to `items()` for 3.x.

Comment: @Lattyware: It would be better to use a dictionary comprehension in 3.x

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions exist in 2.7.3.